# How to compare values using Id from $scope value in html

Tags: angularjs

I want to compare values as new value and old value on the basis of id. I just want to get a condition to put the correct value at the right place

Here is the Html :

```
<div ng-repeat = "values in aAndaData track by $index"> {{aAndaData}}        
                                        <li ng-if="old  != null || new !=null" >
                                            <strong>Account Executive : </strong><span ng-if="data.id==data.id" class="past-data">{{old.fullName}}</span> <i class=" fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> <span ng-if="data.id!=data.id">{{new.fullName}}<!-- {{quotation.accountExecutive.lastName}}--></span>
                                        </li>
                                        </div>
```

PS : How to check the condition
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you save the changed value in different variable, or else you are technically overwriting.

```
$scope.data.id = oldvalue;
$scope.datacc.id = angular.copy(oldValue);

function(somechange) {
    $scope.datacc.id = newValue; 
}
```

that way... ng-if= "data.id == datacc.id"> {{oldvalue}} else newValue. So here if the datacc.id will be in same state as oldvalue initially, but if the value changed then that original value will be overwritten.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can't we manage it at the HTML.? I'm new to angular. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: no, you have to pass in the changed data to controller and pass it back to view... that's how MVC works.